# String split() method, zero and negative limit

Tags: java, string, split

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Here is the syntax of this method: `public String[] split(String regex, int limit)` or `public String[] split(String regex)`

In the above link, I can understand the `Str.split("-", 2)` and `Str.split("-", 3)` examples.

However, I don't quite get the `Str.split("-", 0)`, what's the role of zero of the limit? In some examples, I have also encountered negative limits, what is this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: Copy-pasted for your convenience: "f n  is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded."

Comment: @laune You missed the prior sentence! Not surprising, since *non-positive* isn't **obviously** negative. *If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.* So, a zero discard empty records and a negative preserves them!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, my scanner was definitely set too narrow ;-o Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The **limit** parameter controls the number of times the *pattern* is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting `array`. We have *3* possible *values* for this **limit**:

1. If the limit **n** is greater than *zero* then the pattern will be applied at most **n - 1** times, the `array's` length will be no greater than **n**, and the `array's` last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.
2. If **n** is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the `array` can have any length.
3. If **n** is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the `array` can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: In n is zero, will leading empty strings be discarded too? 0:) before I test it...

Comment: No unfortunately it will not, it will add an element holding one space!

Comment: Take a look at this method:

Comment: public String[] splitWithLead( String input, String limit )
{
    return input.replaceFirst("^" + limit, "").split(limit); 
}

Answer (score 10):

`Str.split("-",0)` is the same as `Str.split("-")`

Answer (score 2):

`Str.split("-", 0)` is equivalent to `Str.split("-")`. I.e, there's no limit.