# scala split ignore last values when empty

Tags: scala

```
scala> val st1 = "|||||||000001|09/01/2014|V|174500,00|22||BD |2540|LEC|1000|BEB|
       01|53||AE|111 ||49|94,22|6||||||||2|2|App|80|2|||"
scala> st1.split('|').length
resXX: Int = 39

scala> val st2 = "|||||||000001|09/01/2014|V|174500,00|22||BD |2540|LEC|1000|BEB|
       01|53||AE|111 ||49|94,22|6||||||||2|2|App|80|2| | |"
scala> st2.split('|').length
resXX: Int = 41
```

that is the last empty fields are ignored by the split.
is there any solution other that replacing all `"||"` by `"| |"`

the expected output is `Int = 41`.

indeed in the real file I may have lines such as:

```
"|||||||000001|09/01/2014|V|174500,00|22||BD |2540|LEC|1000|BEB|
       01|53||AE|111 ||49|94,22|6||||||||2|2|App|80|2|||150"
```

that is a 42nd column comprising a number. (In this case the result is `Int = 42`)

Every line has the same number of `|`, but depending on the content of the column, the `split('|').length` returns a different result! (31, 40, ...,42).

I can understand the lack of the column after the last separator, but not the lack of the previous ones.

Comment: Can you please be more accurate? What is the desired output?

Comment: do you only to ignore the empty ones at the end or at the entire string?

Comment: @NirHedvat I edited my question

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `st1.count(_ == '|')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue comes from Java (since that's where String#split is defined). 
As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701289/4482064), in the default case (which is `limit=0`), the trailing empty strings are discarded.

To make it work as you expect, you can use `str.split('|', -1)`.

Comment: ok but in this case the `'|'` fails. one must use `str.split("""\|""", -1)`.